# How to write RFID data tag?

Tags: rfid

I have an RFID read/writer with the tags and would like to write some data on them. The only thing that the read/writer don't have is the software to write on them. I have downloaded a software and it looks like it is working.

Now the problem I am facing is this. My Client has send be an RFID with data inside. The data written on the tag is 2825-10. When I read the tag with this reader, the data is this: £º3832352D3130000000000000000000262F000000.

Now what I don't understand is what is that data? is it Hex? if yes, when I try to convert it to text it is not becoming the code (2825-10).

Also if you have other software which you think is better, tell m

Thanks,

Keith Spiteri

Comment: The data will be encoded and not just a straight-forward hex to string, have a look [here](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-faq/rfid/#Reading_RFID).

Comment: so why when i tried to write the same code on another tag it is not becoming the same but instead the result is £º0000000000000000000000000000000011223344